# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\bug\Desktop\wp-test\node_modules\react-render-html\node_modules\parse5\lib\serializer

Tags: reactjs

iam try to use react-render-html in my project but im see this error pls help me.
this is body of error:

This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by `npm install util`, and add following into `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
      fallback: {
        util: require.resolve("util/")
      }
  }
  // ...
};
```

Comment: i cant find this file webpack.config.js